# Is CryptMsgGetParam enough to ensure file integrity?

Tags: winapi, cryptography, digital-signature

I have a bunch of code currently to check if the PE is signed by my company but it only checks the signature (not written by me)

```
// hMsg was obtained earlier by using CryptQueryObject
DWORD dwSignerInfo;
bool ret = CryptMsgGetParam(hMsg, 
            CMSG_SIGNER_INFO_PARAM, 
            0, 
            NULL, 
            &dwSignerInfo);

PCMSG_SIGNER_INFO pSignerInfo = NULL;
pSignerInfo = (PCMSG_SIGNER_INFO)LocalAlloc(LPTR, dwSignerInfo);

ret = CryptMsgGetParam(hMsg, 
            CMSG_SIGNER_INFO_PARAM, 
            0, 
            (PVOID)pSignerInfo, 
            &dwSignerInfo);

std::vector<BYTE> fileSerial;
fileSerial.assign(pSignerInfo->SerialNumber.pbData, pSignerInfo->SerialNumber.pbData + pSignerInfo->SerialNumber.cbData);

const std::array<BYTE, 16> k_serial = {0x01,0x01,0x01,0x01,0x01,0x01,0x01,0x01,0x01,0x01,0x01,0x01,0x01,0x01,0x01,0x01}
const std::vector<BYTE> k_SerialKey(k_serial.cbegin(), k_serial.cend());

if (fileSerial == k_SerialKey)
{
    // Do stuff since signature is made by us
}
```

The above code looks like it works well enough but it doesn't seem tp really check the integrity of the file itself. I want to be able to verify that the executable did not get corrupted by a virus or something but kept the signature intact.

I was thinking that I can keep using CryptMsgGetParam and use the params

CMSG_COMPUTED_HASH_PARAM

CMSG_HASH_DATA_PARAM

These params return 2 different hashes, if I compare them and they match does it mean that my file matches the hash in the signature?

N.B. I looked at WinVerifyTrust but I feel like its wayyy overkill for what I want, all I want is verify the file still matches the file the signature was made for.

Comment: I imagine you would use `CMSG_CTRL_VERIFY_HASH` to verify the integrity of the file.  But the documentation is a bit confusing.